# Create Outlook email with an @Mention for a contact in the body

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

I'm generating an Outlook email, which has an HTML body, via Excel VBA.

I would like to @ a contact in my organisation in the body. e.g. @Bloggs, Joe

`Mention` is a functionality added to Outlook in the last few years and it seems it's an HTML link. How do I ensure Outlook formats this `mention` correctly?

Would the below suffice for Outlook to recognise this as a mention?

```
<a href="mailto:Joe.Bloggs@MyOrg.com">
<span style='font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;mso-no-proof:yes;text-decoration:none; text-underline:none'>@Bloggs, Joe</span>
```

Comment: No. With some testing, it looks like there is typically an id= (random string of letters/numbers) in front of the href inside the `a` element. If you can figure out how to get that id value-my guess is its static, you should be able to insert that directly. Otherwise it just formats as an html click through, not a @mentions.

Comment: There seems to be some underlying CSS in there if you search for "Mentions" in the html produced. Would that share any light?

Comment: Reviewing the HTML of the body doesn't show anything explicitly for Mentions except the text formatting.  When adding a Mention the only real difference I found between the Hyperlink version and the @Mentions version was the addition of the id tag in the element. `<a id= ~stringOfLettersAndNumbers~ href="mailto:email@email.email">`  I dug around through the contacts, address and exchange properties and couldn't find the one this ID referenced. Hopefully someone else will stumble on an answer for you.  The ID didn't seem to change so perhaps worst case scenario you can build a list and use that

Comment: Alas, even using the id in the HTML doesn't seem to make Outlook recognise the mention

Answer (score 23):

The trick seems to be in the `id` of the anchor tag:

- Each ID needs to start with `OWAAM` (I suspect it stands for "Outlook Web Access At Mention", as that's where the feature originated), followed by a 32 character hex value, followed by `Z`.
- Each ID needs to be unique in the document, but doesn't have to be unique for the mention, so you can just generate a new one for each mention.

For instance:

```html
<a id="OWAAM954ABFF4E42A42989C2192D3F93BB32DZ" 
   href="mailto:immo@example.com">Immo Landwerth</a>
```

This code works for me (C#):

```
static string GetMentionHtml(string email, string name)
{
    var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").ToUpper();
    var id = $"OWAAM{guid}Z";
    return = $"<a id=\"{id}\" href=\"mailto:{email}\">@{name}</a>";
}
```

And in case you need it in VBA:

```vb
Function GetMentionHtml(email As String, name As String) As String
    Dim id As String
    Dim html As String    
    id = "OWAAM" & NewGuid() & "Z"
    html = "<a id=""" & id & """ href=""mailto:" & email & """>@" & name & "</a>"
    GetMentionHtml = html
End Function

' Sadly there is no "get me a GUID" in VBA, but this is good enough.
' Source: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/vb/excel+vba+generate+guid+uuid
Function NewGuid() As String
    Dim k&, h$
    NewGuid = Space(36)
    For k = 1 To Len(NewGuid)
        Randomize
        Select Case k
            Case 9, 14, 19, 24: h = "-"
            Case 15:            h = "4"
            Case 20:            h = Hex(Rnd * 3 + 8)
            Case Else:          h = Hex(Rnd * 15)
        End Select
        Mid$(NewGuid, k, 1) = h
    Next
    NewGuid = Replace(NewGuid, "-", vbNullString, Compare:=vbTextCompare)
End Function
```

Comment: Hmm...it still seems more is needed. This looks like the HTML of the email, but yet when it is sent, it does not have the "@" symbol attached to the email item and therefore does not get categorised into "Mentioned Mail"

Comment: Have you tried including the `@` symbol in the content of the anchor? I've updated my answer. I've looked at the resulting HTML in Outlook and there are no obvious other markers.

Also, it seems it takes Outlook a moment to realize there are mentions. My outbox has no `@` icon for a few seconds and then it appears.

Comment: I've played a bit with VBA in Outlook, trying to send emails that get recognized with mentions and I can't seem to be able to do that. However, my method works when you paste the generated HTML into Outlook, so I suspect the mail editor adds some additional data into the email that the VBA code can't add.

Comment: Is there like an Outlook equivalent of ActiveSheet.Calculate which would add all of these things?