# How to tag recipients in Outlook mail body via VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office365

In Outlook, you have the option to tag a recipient using `@'required emailid'` in the mail body. Email will be highlighted for all tagged recipients.

I have 2 columns in Excel.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| @user1, @user2 | sit |
| @user3, @user1 | stand |

I want these values to be read from Excel and create a text string and put on mail body, like:

> @User1, @User2. Please sit
> @user3, @User1. Please stand.

where each userid is tagged/linked.

Below is the code that I have tried. It is pasting the '@User1' etc. as simple text and not as tags-

```
Sub send_mail_test()

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
        
    un = Application.UserName
    rr = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).row
        
    Subj = "This is a test mail"
    
    body = "<p>" & "Hi All," & "</p>" & _
    "<p>" & "Below is the list of tasks - " & "</p>" & _
    "<p>" & "Action Items - " & "<br />" & "<ol>"
    
    For i = 2 To rr
        If Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
            body = body & "<li>" & sh.Cells(i, 1).Value & ". Please - " & sh.Cells(i, 2) & "</li>"
        End If
    Next i
    
    body = body & "</ol>" & "</p>" & _
            "<p>" & "Thanks," & "<br />" & un & "</p>"
        
    ' SET Outlook APPLICATION OBJECT.
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    ' CREATE EMAIL OBJECT.
    Dim objEmail As Object
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With objEmail
        .To = "ABC@XYZ.COM"
        .Cc = "ABC@XYZ.COM"
        .Subject = Subj
        .HTMLbody = body
        .Display        ' DISPLAY MESSAGE.
    End With
    
    ' CLEAR.
    
    Set objEmail = Nothing:    Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). What went wrong, what works so far? Where is the code that creates the text? • Also see [ask].

Comment: I have updated the question with a sample code.

Comment: See [Create Outlook email with an @Mention for a contact in the body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58214117/create-outlook-email-with-an-mention-for-a-contact-in-the-body) and [VBA - dynamically create @mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66150726/how-to-tag-recipients-in-outlook-mail-body-via-vba?noredirect=1#comment116953548_66150726) • Looks like there is no way to create that with VBA properly.